# This string come out false on my console while on a regex tester it came out true any idea?

Tags: javascript, regex, backslash

```
console.log(/^\\[Xx][a-z][0-9]/.test('\xd8'));
```

Comment: $20 says that this is an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: how can i fix it ??

Answer (score 2):

`\x` is an escape sequence for other cases. `\xd8` is the escaped value for `Ø`.

This means, your regex test never saw any of those characters you entered. Therefore the result has to be `false`.

If you want to match those strings, you need to escape the basckslash:

```
a = '\\xd8';
console.log(/^\\[Xx][a-z][0-9]/.test(a));
```

Comment: are you talking to yourself :-)

Comment: the pobleme is  \xd8 is what i get from raw html data after scrapping a website  .